# testing anyOf in json schema where value must be true

Tags: jsonschema

I'm validating a json scheme where I need to check if the json has an array of 'activities', and if not, if it has a 'live' attribute which must be true.

My schema is quite simple `note the enum is not working`

```
const viewSchema = {
    "type": "object",
    "anyOf": [
        {"required": ["live"]},
        {"required": ["activities"]}
    ],
    "properties":{
        "title": {"type": "string"},
        "live": {"type": "boolean", "enum": [ true ]},
        "activities": {"type": "array"}

    }
```

So I am trying to validate against the following

```
isValid({title: 'a title'}) // false:  activities or live required
isValid({title: 'a title', activities: []}) // true
isValid({title: 'a title', live: true}) // true
isValid({title: 'a title', live: false) // true - this should be false
```

Comment: Your schema is correct.  If you are getting the wrong result, it's probably a bug in the validator.

Comment: Testet your schema with the validator on http://www.jsonschemavalidator.net
For this json {title: 'a title', live: false} i get Found 1 error(s)
Message:
Value false is not defined in enum.
So, your schema is ok.

Answer (score 2):

It's a little redundant, but you can use [oneOf](https://spacetelescope.github.io/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html#oneof) and two distinct schema to achieve this.

Here's an example using AJV:

```js
// Code goes here

var ajv = new Ajv({
  $data: true,
  verbose: true
});

let schema = {
  "type": "object",
  "oneOf": [{
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "live": {
          "type": "boolean",
          "enum": [true]
        },
      },
      "required": ["live"]
    },
    {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "activities": {
          "type": "array"
        }
      },
      "required": ["activities"]
    }
  ]
};


ajv.validate(schema, {
  title: 'a title'
}) // false:  activities or live required
console.log('ERRORS: ', this.ajv.errors)
ajv.validate(schema, {
  title: 'a title',
  activities: []
}) // true
console.log('ERRORS: ', this.ajv.errors)
ajv.validate(schema, {
  title: 'a title',
  live: true
}) // true
console.log('ERRORS: ', this.ajv.errors)
ajv.validate(schema, {
  title: 'a title',
  live: false
}) // this is now invalid
console.log('ERRORS: ', this.ajv.errors)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ajv/5.3.0/ajv.bundle.js"></script>
```